# Queries in MS Access sometimes execute from contructor or SQL modes very slowly

Tags: sql, ms-access

Sometimes all sql queries in my MS Access database execute very slowly (about 1 min) when launching from constructor or SQL modes. When starting the same queries immediately from query panel, they execute very fast (less than 1 sec). Such behaviour doesn't depend on complexity of query: it may be even simple query like `select from` little table. Database is local, with no attempt to require data from network.

Thanks in advance for any idea

Comment: What do you mean by "constructor modes", "SQL modes" and "query panel"?  Do you perhaps mean "Design View", "SQL View" and the "Navigation pane"?

Comment: C Perkins, thanks for reply. Yes, I meant that all queries works slowly from Design and SQL views (when switching to Table view), and works normally when launching from Navigation pane. Sorry for my English (I have a local MS Office).

Comment: I did a web search for `access query design view very slow` and got a few good pages. Is this new behavior or has it started recently?  Does it only occur with one database or any database?  (Try creating a new dummy database and see if it happens.)  Does closing and restarting Access affect it?  Have you installed or changed default printer setting?

Comment: CPerkins, thanks for reply. I've created dummy database with a table `test` with one field (of `integer` type) and one row. I see that a query `select * from test` switches from Design view to a Table view for about a minute. Moreover, if open this table `test` in Design view, and then switch it to Table view, it takes about a minute too. Why? I don't remember such behaviour previously.

Comment: Honestly I don't really know.  But a recent 2013 and 2016 Office update caused other problems that has caused many to roll back changes.  Perhaps you could roll back to an earlier version of office of see if it has an effect.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2770432/how-to-revert-to-an-earlier-version-of-office-2013-or-office-2016-clic

Comment: C Perkins, I have Office 2010. Anyway, thanks for trying to help. Maybe, I'll try to reinstall MS Access or the whole Office.